# Java Predicate Interface - How the method is working - Though it is not implemented in my class

Tags: java, interface, predicate

Though I have not implemented the method - test - which is in Predicate interface, how come the method is executed without any body in my class - inte??

```
package newone; 
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class inte {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate <Integer> p = i -> (i<19);
        System.out.println(  p.test(22));
       }


@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T var1);
}
```

Comment: This is just syntactic sugar for an anonymous inner class.

Comment: p is a predicate. test() is like accept() in  a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

Comment: It would be helpful for me if I know why negative rating was given. As a learner, I am going through the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Though I have not implemented the method - test

You have, with the lambda expression:

```java
Predicate <Integer> p = i -> (i<19);
```

That's *mostly like*:

```java
Predicate<Integer> p = new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer i) {
        return i < 19;
    }
};
```

The exact details in the bytecode are a little different, but for the most part you can think of a lambda expression as shorthand for creating an anonymous inner class. The compiler is able to perform other tricks to avoid creating extra classes in reality, at least in some cases - it depends on what your lambda expression does.

Comment: Thanks, this has puzzled me a lot! And this solved many of my other questions about Anonymous classes and functional interfaces as well.

Answer (score 3):

Newer compiler<sup>1</sup>, starting with version 8 (I believe), add a (synthetic) method to the code, *mostly like*:

```
public class Inte {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Integer> p = Inte::lambda$test$1;
        ...
    }
    // synthetic
    private static boolean lambda$test$1(Integer i) {
        return i < 19;
    }
}
```

<sup>**1** - alternatively, and before Java version 8, an additional class implementing the interface can be added (like an anonymous class)</sup>

Comment: I specifically say "the exact details in the bytecode are a little different" - the use of an anonymous class is to make it easier to understand how this is implementing an interface. I would suggest that this answer just moves the question on from "how does a lambda expression implement an interface" to "how does a method reference implement an interface". (I've added a little bit more detail to the end of the answer though.)

Comment: @Jon I am not trying to compete with you, sorry (shouldn't be any problem for you to change or delete this answer - even if it wasn;t marked as community wiki)

Comment: No problem - I'm sorry for getting overly defensive, too.